# Why Not working Delete Button in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am going to delete files in My laravel app. but delete button not working. (not deleted) No any Error blade.php

```
//delete button here
                            <button class="btn btn-danger delete pull-right"
                            data-action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/files/{{ $file->id }}"
                            data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
                            </button>
```

Controller

```
public function deleteOneProjectFile($fileUrl, $id)
    {
        DB::table('files')
            ->where('file_url', $fileUrl)
            ->where('project_id', $id)
            ->delete();

        return redirect()->route('projects.show')->with('info', 'File deleted successfully');
    }
```

routes

```
Route::delete('projects/{projects}/files/{files}',[
'uses' => 'FilesController@deleteOneProjectFile',
    ]);
```

how can solve this problem?

Comment: What problems/errors are you experiencing? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No any error..Not delete file when I clicked delete button

Answer (score 0):

According to me you're not requesting the server as DELETE Request, thats why its not working, you can use Laravel's way to achieve this:

Your Routes file should be like:

```
Route::delete('projects/{projects}/files/{files}', 'FilesController@deleteOneProjectFile')->name('delete_route');
```

and your HTML should be like:

```
<form action="{{ route('delete_route', ['project_id' => $project_id, 'file_id' => $file_id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_token() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    ......

    <button type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't get you!